# Ansible: Intersection of two host groups using yaml inventory

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have 2 groups, each with child groups called `dev` and `test`.  I am trying to target `test` hosts in `group2` (`four.example.com`) using the pattern `group2:&test`.

Given the yaml inventory:

```
all:
  children:
    group1:
      children:
        dev:
          hosts:
            one.example.com:
        test:
          hosts:
            two.example.com:
    group2:
      children:
        dev:
          hosts:
            three.example.com:
        test:
          hosts:
            four.example.com:
```

And playbook:

```
- name: health check
  hosts: group2:&test
  tasks:
    - name: Ping hosts
      ping:
```

I am getting pings back from both `two` and `four`.

I expect pings from **only** `four`.

Although it's true that `two` is part of a group called `test`, it is **not** part of the group called `group2`, and I therefore would not expect to see it as part of the intersect.

It's as though it's doing a logical or (||), rather than a logical and (&&)

Is this a limitation of Ansible when using nested groups with non-unique child names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: **"*Is this a limitation of Ansible when using nested groups with non-unique child names?*"**

A: Ansible by design doesn't store the inventory tree. This might seem a limitation. Quoting from  [How variables are merged](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-variables-are-merged)

> By default variables are merged/flattened to the specific host before a play is run. This keeps Ansible focused on the Host and Task, so groups don’t really survive outside of inventory and host matching.

Quoting from [Inheriting variable values: group variables for groups of groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups)

> Any host that is a member of a child group is automatically a member of the parent group.

There are 2 implications

1. The [patern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#using-patterns) '*group2:&test*' is a self-contradiction. The group *test* contains hosts: *two* and *four*. You agree on this by having tried the intersection. Otherwise, the intersection wouldn't make sense. But the quoted statement says that members of *test* are automatically members of both *group1* and *group2*. In other words, Ansible can't tell the difference between 1) the group *test* keeping all hosts and 2) the group *test* as a child of *group1* or *group2*. As an example, the inventories below are equivalent to the inventory in the question

```yaml
all:
  children:
    group1:
      children:
        dev:
          hosts:
            one.example.com:
            three.example.com:
        test:
          hosts:
            two.example.com:
            four.example.com:
    group2:
      children:
        dev:
        test:
```

```yaml
all:
  children:
    dev:
      hosts:
        one.example.com:
        three.example.com:
    test:
      hosts:
        two.example.com:
        four.example.com:
    group1:
      children:
        dev:
        test:
    group2:
      children:
        dev:
        test:
```

2. The nested groups with non-unique child names don't serve the purpose of this use-case. Try the inventory below instead

```yaml
all:
  children:
    group1:
      hosts:
        one.example.com:
        two.example.com:
    group2:
      hosts:
        three.example.com:
        four.example.com:
    dev:
      hosts:
        one.example.com:
        three.example.com:
    test:
      hosts:
        two.example.com:
        four.example.com:
```

---

Notes

- There might be differences among the inventories in which order the groups_vars will be merged if used. See [How variables are merged](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-variables-are-merged).

Comment: If I use unique names (group1_dev, group2_test, etc) for the child groups it works as expected, so if I understand correctly, the flattening results in a singe group called test, which belongs to both group1 and group2.  Thanks for your answer

Comment: You're welcome. Right. Let me add to this. If you use unique names the intersect won't be needed.

Comment: Yes.  Perhaps unconventional, but the idea is that I can still target all 'group1' nodes if I need to, while also storing the groups in a way that cleary conveys info that, perhaps, an env manager might care about.  (For example, I consume this yml in jenkins to create drop-down lists of target hosts, per environment)